# Imagemagick: How to improve the brightness/contrast of an image with a narrow histogram?

Tags: image-processing, automation, imagemagick, image-manipulation, imagemagick-convert

I have a dark image which histogram lies in a tight group.

[image: A source image]

[image: The image histogram]

In image editor I can convert image int HSL colorspace, separate L channels and make histogram adjustment.

[image: Histogram adjustment dialog]

Is this the right way? Which next steps are necessary to do?

Is there a universal solution how to work with such histogram and improve image brightness/contrast?

How can I do the same thing with ImageMagick?

Comment: does that thing have a way to stretch the histogram to 1st and 99th percentile, per channel, while respecting gamma compression? -- that "tight group" is ***NOT*** the whole image content, it's just the bright background. your image content lies between that and blackness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple method in Imagemagick is simply -auto-level.

Input:

[image]

```
convert img.png -auto-level result.png
```

[image]

If you want to replicate what you did, then in Unix syntax, convert your level parameters to percents: low=100*87/255=34.1% and high=100*141/255=55.3% and gamma=1.83

```
convert img.png -colorspace LAB -separate -write mpr:LAB \
\( mpr:LAB[0] -level 34.1%,55.3%,1.83 \) \
-swap 0,3 +delete \
-set colorspace LAB -combine -colorspace sRGB \
result.png
```

[image]

For Windows, remove the \ from the parentheses and change the end of line \ to ^.  Double the % if in .bat file.

Comment: What does `-swap 0,3 +delete` do: swap two channels L and B? The other I think I understand

Comment: It swaps the original L with the modified L then deletes the original L before Lmodified, A, B are recombined. The original L is image 0, A is image 1, B is image 2 and the new modified L is image 3 before the swap.

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear to me what it is in your image that is of interest to you, so it's hard to know what to optimise for, so I just share my thoughts on processing it. Adapt, adopt and discard according to your needs.

---

Firstly, it has an entirely superfluous alpha channel, so I would discard that by starting any processing with:

```
magick image.png -alpha off ...
```

---

Secondly, the histograms for the three colours look almost identical in width and shape so I don't perceive there to be much colour information so I would go for greyscale processing. If we split the image into its RGB channels and lay them out side-by-side across the page with their contrast maximised we get:

```
magic image.png -alpha off -separate -auto-level +append RGB.jpg
```

[image]

There doesn't appear to me to be much difference between the channels, and in fact, the blue and the red look slightly noisier, so I would drop them and take green as my single channel. Take `L` of `Lab` mode in preference or make a greyscale conversion as you wish.

---

Now we need to look at contrast. As you have heavy vignetting (or similar) in the corners, and I presume that is not your area of interest, I would take the central 70% of the image and get its minimum and maximum value for use in a contrast stretch for the entire image:

```
magick pGmg9.png  -alpha off -gravity center -crop 70% -channel G -separate -format "%[min],%[max]" info:
13364,34695
```

So now I know the central region is between 16-bit brightness values of 13,364 to 34,695.

---

Now I want to use those two values as the lower and upper limits for a contrast-stretch, to which I can apply a gamma as well - but again I don't know what you are looking for:

Here's a gamma of 2:

```
convert pGmg9.png  -alpha off -channel G -separate -level 13364,34695,2 result.jpg
```

[image]

Here's a gamma of 1:

```
convert pGmg9.png  -alpha off -channel G -separate -level 13364,34695,1 result.jpg
```

[image]

Here's a gamma of 0.5:

```
convert pGmg9.png  -alpha off -channel G -separate -level 13364,34695,0.5 result.jpg
```

[image]

---

Or, you may prefer to simply discard the bottom 6% of darkest pixels and the top 3% of brightest pixels and do a linear stretch in between:

```
magick pGmg9.png  -alpha off -channel G -separate -contrast-stretch 6%x3% result.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: OP needs to clean their lens! :)

Comment: This is a microscopic image. The black spots are microorganisms. I'm intrested in separating them from the background.